# couldn't execute promgen in vivado tcl

Tags: fpga, vivado

I want to generate the binary file.bin and I thought that it is possible in Vivado 2014.3 IDE

It seems like the command promgen doesn't exist?

[image]

How can I get an appropriate binary to use later in parallella board , it should have the header file

Comment: Have you tried to run your program in a normal console? Does the Vivado TCL console support PATH?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a .bin file from the tcl console, the command you're looking for is `write_bitstream` which is documented in the [Vivado Design Suite Tcl Command Reference Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_4/ug835-vivado-tcl-commands.pdf).
As @Paebbels mentioned there may be a way to use the `promgen` command from the command line (its not a tcl command), but I haven't ever tried that so I'm not sure.  You can run the equivalent of the promgen tool (I believe PROMGen was an ISE tool) through the GUI if you connect to a device in the Hardware Manager (no longer called iMPACT in Vivado).
Finally if you need to create a .mcs file in a Tcl script you can use the `write_cfgmem` Tcl command (see the reference guide for more info).